# Postgresql database table datas returns TypeError ... is not JSON serializable in python

Tags: python, serialization, jupyter-notebook

I'm setting up some python code in my Jupyter Notebook for a Machine Learning project using Ibm Watson and I keep getting a `TypeError is not JSON serializable` when I try to add datas from my Postgresql database.

Here's the full output for clarity:

```
TypeError:                                           description
0   Lorem ipsum sjvh  hcx bftiyf,  hufcil, igfgvju...
1   Lorem ajjgvc wiufcfboitf iujcvbnb hjnkjc  ivjh...
2   Lorem aiv ibveikb jvk igvcib ok blnb v  hb b h...
3   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
4   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
5   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
6   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
7   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
8   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
9   Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
10     lorem sivbnogc hbiuygv bnjiuygv bmkjygv nmjhgv
11  Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
12  Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
13  Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
14  Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
15  Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
16  Lorem jsvc smc cbd ciecdbbc d vd bcvdvbj obcvb...
17  lore  juhgv bnmkiuhygv nmkiuhb mkjiuhb mkjgv m...
18  Lorem uhygfv bniuhgv nmkjuhgv nmkijuhygv mkihv... is not JSON serializable
```

And This is my python code that deploy the ML models to analyze theses datas which are random sentences as you can see, but will be product descriptions after testing:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageClassifierV1
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2


# Connecting to my database.
conn_string = 'host={} port={}  dbname={}  user={}  password={}'.format('159.***.20.***', 5432, 'searchdb', 'lcq09', 'Mys3cr3tPass')
conn_cbedce9523454e8e9fd3fb55d4c1a52e = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
data_df_1 = pd.read_sql('SELECT description from public."search_product"', con=conn_cbedce2drf563454e8e9fd3fb8776fgh2e)

# Connecting to the ML model.
natural_language_classifier = NaturalLanguageClassifierV1(
    iam_apikey='TB97dFv8Dgug6rfi945F3***************'
)

# Apply the ML model to db datas
classes = natural_language_classifier.classify('9841d0z5a1-ncc-9076', data_df_1)
print(json.dumps(classes, indent=2))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: the parameter named "classes" that goes within json.dumps, It's type should be dict I think, please check that.

Comment: I tried replacing the parameter `classes` with `dict` like this: `print(json.dumps(dict, indent=2))` but it doesn't work!

Comment: No you need to convert the type of "classes" to "dict". "dict" is a data type in python, the variable "classes" is not of data type dict, that would be the reason of this error.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure to fully understand, so could you include a simple example?